# How to use a simple modular architecture on Quasar Vue?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vite, quasar

does anyone have any examples, how I can use a simple modular architecture in Quasar on vue 3 + Pinia + Vite store
I need to get this file structure:
[example structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Y1ND.jpg)

I tried to follow this example - https://github.com/DarkC0der11/vue-modular-architecture
but it didn't work, there was an error with the router (the example uses vuex, but I need pinia), and I don't have main.js file

perhaps i need to connect the module via boot in the quasar config?
I do not understand how to assemble such a structure so that the project starts without errors